# How to remove a object inside an array list

Tags: java, object

I have searched a lot for this, and checked the posts that is provided as possible answers, and none seems to give me an answer.

I have this arraylist in which i store online users. 
I can read from the user list and add to it. 
Problem is, I cant seem to find out how I remove it.

I have tried

```
online.remove("MyUsername");
```

My class and initialiser is like this:

```
 ArrayList<userOnline> online = new ArrayList<userOnline>();

   class userOnline {
        String userName;
        String data1;
        String data2;
        String data3;
    }
```

I thought it would find the object row with username and remove the row, or at least the username, but it removed nothing and does not give me any errors.

What can I do to make it work? Or what can I use as an alternative if this is not possible? A pointer to a doc explaining would be more than enough help!

Thanks!

Seemed like the solution was this, but this is not considered good practice

```
for (int i=0; i <online.size(); i++) {
    if(online.get(i).userName.equals("username")) {
        online.remove(i);
    }
}
```

After a discussion and a lot of feedback seems like the only right way for java to handle this search and remove is,

```
  Iterator<userOnline> it = online.iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
          userOnline user = it.next();
          if (currentLogin.equals(user.userName)) {
              it.remove();
          }
     }
```

Comment: You need to define equals() for userOnline class so to be able to locate and remove the object.

Comment: You can either remove using the index of the element or remove using the element's object

Comment: but not making `equals()` return true for a String

Comment: Or you will need to search the `List` of a corresponding element and remove it either by the reference of the object or index point

Comment: Ok, Like i do where i find if a user is online, there i do a for loop to run through and do an equals then print. is that what you mean?

Comment: @KristianMartinsen *"Solution was"* - is NOT the right solution; How is a `userOnline` with the `userName` `A` and `data1` of `B` equal to a `userOnline` with the `userName` `A` and `data1` of `C`?  Your approach is violating the contract required by `equals` and will get you into no end of trouble, just about any of the other answers would be better

Comment: @MadProgrammer I dont understand what the problem is? data1,2,3 is never involved in the equation?

Comment: I mean, the i is the same for all the cols in the user array "rows" in online?

Comment: @KristianMartinsen That's my point, `equals` should compare ALL the properties of the two objects, otherwise they can't be equal

Comment: but the check is only asking to check username, which is what i want to check and then remove the row, still don't see what the problem is? the row was removed so they must have been equal? thats how it works?

Comment: @KristianMartinsen No, that's not how `equals` is suppose to work.  `equals` defines a contract where one instance of an object can be compared to another for equality of it's properties, not just one, as I stated earlier, the way you're "trying" to use it is erroneous and will you into a trouble quickly, it's also not customisable, what happens when you want to remove an object based on the value of `data1`, just because you have a narrow field requirement, doesn't mean you should violate the expected functionality of well defined and documented API just because it's convenient at the time

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I'm very frustrated here. they all use equals below? Is it the iterator and equals that make it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can't compare apples and pears (`String` and `userOnline`) directly.  Yes you could override `equals`, but it should really match all the properties, not just one.

A simple solution would be to search the `List`, comparing each objects `userName` property with the value you want an either return the `index` or object reference, which you could use to remove it.

Alternatively, you could use an `Iterator` and remove it as you search...

```
ArrayList<userOnline> online = new ArrayList<>();
userOnline newUser = new userOnline();
newUser.userName = "MyUsername";
online.add(newUser);
System.out.println(online.size());
Iterator<userOnline> it = online.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    userOnline user = it.next();
    if ("MyUsername".equals(user.userName)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
System.out.println(online.size());
```

There's probably also a really cool "streams" based solution, but small steps ;)

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't find a dupe or a suitable doc, so here it is:

Use an `Iterator`:

```
for (Iterator<userOnline> iterator = online.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    if (iterator.next().getName().equals("MyUsername")) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will remove/search all objects with "MyUsername" in each of the online arrays right? So it is good for doing a search etc?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function that takes in your list of users and finds the first occurence of a given name and removes it when it finds a user with the name given like so

```
public Array<userOnline> removeUserByName(Array<userOnline> users, String nameToFind)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++)
    {
        if(users.get(i).userName.equals(nameToFind))
        {
            users.remove(i);
            return users;
        }
    }
    return users;
}
```

You could also make this function part of the class you store your list of userOnline objects then you wouldn't have to pass the array into the function.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the list to find the index of the element you are interested in:

```
 int idx = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < online.size(); i++) {
        if(online.get(i).userName.equals("MyUsername"))
        {
            idx = i;
        }
    }
```

Use this index to remove the relevant element:

```
if(idx != -1) {
    online.remove(online[idx]);
}
```

This would only remove the first occurrence. You could put this code into a function and call repeatedly to find all occurrences.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks. Several different programming languages were used today.

Comment: Yep, tell me about it :P

Comment: @sgrg , could you explain the difference between the answer i added in my post and this one?

Answer (score 2):

You must search through the userOnline objects contained within your ArrayList and either find the index of the match or a reference to the match.  Once you have either of these, you can remove the object from the list using one of the overloaded remove() methods.  Remember that by default, the equals method compares references.

The search can be as follows:

```
private userOnline findUserOnlineWithUsername(String username) {
    Iterator<userOnline> it = online.iterator();
    onlineUser olu = null;

    while(it.hasNext()) {
        olu = it.next();
        if (olu.userName.equals(username)) { return olu;}
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is asking to remove a String from a List of UserOnlines, you need to use the object reference for the remove(Object o) method, or you need to find out the index of the object you wish to remove and use the remove(int index) method. How are you adding your objects to the list? If you're using the list itself as a reference you'll need to create your own method to define what object "MyUserName" is supposed to be.

Comment: Ok,  I'm creating a new userOnline(); and put the variables to the new user and I add new user to the arraylist.

Comment: If you're doing something like the following: UserOnline myUser = new UserOnline() then you can just do list.remove(myUser). However if you're doing list.add(new UserOnline()) as others have mentioned you have to define how you're program finds the object you want. There's been a few suggestions for looking at your name field if that's what you want to use.